# How to change existing Oracle DB Initialization parameter

Tags: oracle, initialization

I am connect with my AWS RDS Oracle DB instance through SQL developer. Now I want to change DB initialization parameters like NLS_LANGUAGE, NLS_DATE_FORMAT... etc.

How can I modify it. Is there any way to change from SQLPLUS or SQL DEVELOPER or AWS DB instances?

**For example:**

I used below comment

`ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY' scope=both;`
Once I executed this comment it showing error as

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY' scope=both
Error report -
ORA-02096: specified initialization parameter is not modifiable with this option
02096. 00000 -  "specified initialization parameter is not modifiable with this option"
*Cause:    Though the initialization parameter is modifiable, it cannot be
           modified using the specified command.
*Action:   Check the DBA guide for information about under what scope
           the parameter may be modified
```

Comment: Do you really want to change the database parameters, or just your session parameters (e.g. in SQL Developer from Tools->Preferences->Database->NLS, or with `alter session` calls)?

Comment: @AlexPoole we are having dump file which have data in Japanese, and client gave their DB NLS parameter setting. we are trying to modify my DB with their NLS parameters. So that we are trying use ```alter system``` option to change in all sessions permeantly.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I have edited my question, please refer example alter query.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for, for example, [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/NLS_DATE_FORMAT.html), show that it is only modifiable in a running instance with `ALTER SESSION`.

If you want to change it for the system you would have to do:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY' scope=spfile;
```

so the server parameter file (spfile) is updated, rather than both that and the in-memory value; and then restart the database.

However, I would still question the need to do this. You don't need your NLS settings to match to perform an import, and as the documentation also says, "The initialization parameter value is, therefore, usually ignored." Any user, client or application connecting to the database can (and probably will) override it with their own session values, making the DB-level ones generally irrelevant; and you shouldn't be relying on NLS settings in any code or processing.